# Apache vhost Configuration

Tags: apache

Please can anyone help with how to setup apache to serve multiple apps on different ports for an external public ip ?
My current host configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin devops57@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost.com
    ServerAlias www.localhost.com
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerAdmin devops57@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/litebridge/public"
    ServerName litebridge.com
    ServerAlias www.litebridge.com
    ErrorLog "logs/litebridge.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/litebridge.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please make sure your question is formatted correctly

Comment: So what is the problem with what you have?

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you want the 2 sites on different port numbers? Would it not be easier to use them if they were both on port 80??

Comment: Its a laravel application that am trying to deloy but i dont want to run it with the public in url. I have multiple apps on that server

Answer (score 0):

To get Apache listening on multiple ports you should use the [Listen directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#listen).

```
Listen 80
Listen 8888

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin devops57@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    ServerName localhost.com
    ServerAlias www.localhost.com
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerAdmin devops57@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/litebridge/public"
    ServerName litebridge.com
    ServerAlias www.litebridge.com
    ErrorLog "logs/litebridge.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/litebridge.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: _Just a small point_ OP would already have a `Listen 80` in `httpd.conf` so you only need to add the `Listen 8888` in `httpd-vhosts.conf`

Comment: I have it listening to port 8888. Am able to access it locally but on the external ip it doesnt work.

Comment: Do these 2 domain name actually exist? And are they pointing to your WAN IP address from a DNS Server?

Comment: @Ricchard It could be your firewall.

Comment: It could also be that your Router is not port forwarded for port 8888

Answer (score 0):

First, if your domain name `litebridge.com` is real and a DNS Server is pointing to your IP address you dont need to use seperate port numbers.

Apache will look at the domain name on the incoming request and decide which site to serve by comparing that with your Virtual Host definitions.

Secondly, you need to tell Apache it is allowed to accept connections and from where those connections can be from, in a `<Directory>` section.
Here I have assumed `localhost` would only be accessed from the PC running the server, so I used `Require local`. And `litebridge.com` shoudl be accessible from anywhere so I used `Require all granted`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin devops57@gmail.com
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/"
    <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog "logs/localhost.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/localhost.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin devops57@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/litebridge/public"
    ServerName litebridge.com
    ServerAlias www.litebridge.com

    <Directory  "C:/xampp/htdocs/litebridge/public/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "logs/litebridge.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/litebridge.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: the domain is not registered yet

Comment: Could you use a Dynamic DNS Service to point to your WAN IP like DYNDNS.COM